# Declarative questions and "some" vs "any"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct:

> There is *some* difference?
>
> There is *any* difference?

If both, what is the difference?

Comment: Those sentences should be *Is there some difference?* and *Is there any difference?* The first tends to be used when we suspect there is a difference but we are not sure what it is (*is there some difference, then?*). The second is the basic form, I would say.

Comment: @Minty No, they shouldn't, those are declarative questions, they basically convey surprise.. e.g. someone says "Don't worry about the difference between bla bla bla" and you say "there is some difference?". It's quite informal I guess but saying "is there some difference?" would make no sense as they've already told you that so it would be dumb to ask like that.

Comment: One issue here is that the idiomatic way of asking the question is simply "There's a difference?!" without using *some* or *any* at all.

Comment: I see - I assumed that *declarative questions* was just a mistake. In that case the second one does not work. It has to be *there is some difference?* or *there is a difference?*

Comment: @AndrewLeach You have a good point. So let's use a different word, e.g. "There are some people" vs "there are any people". WDYT?

Comment: @Minty That's what I thought, thank you.

Comment: A great deal depends on how they are pronounced. This is entirely rhetorical in print, but in speech stress and intonation are important. Also, it's not clear how the _italicized words_ are to be pronounced -- is this just to point out the difference, or does it indicate stress?

Comment: I think if you want to change the question you should change the question, not bury it in a comment, and then (as a matter of courtesy) comment on the existing answer if your revised question invalidates it. Prof Lawler's comment is valid. With regards to people, the question would almost certainly be "There are people?" with no quantifier at all and a surprised stress on *people*; *some* might be used if there **are** people but you can't see them, but that's an extra word which isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

We use some in a question when we think the answer will be 'yes'. On the other hand we use any when we think the answer will be 'no'.

Comment: I think this sort of "declarative" question is actually rhetorical, and doesn't expect an answer at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yeah, I think you are right, it could expect an answer in similar cases, I think.